# How to remove an item from 2 array's with the same order?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I am trying to remove 2 items from 2 different array's. One with value and one without value but has the same order as the first array.(also I am using discord.js).
Here's the code- https://sourceb.in/gUtLbIMoBr
I can't upload it here as it contains more then 50 lines.
Please help.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - Add a [mcve] _in the question itself_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove an item from an array like this. And you can it do it multiple times.

When asking a question show your example code and go into more detail.

```js
let arr = ["a","b","c"]
let arr2 = ["A","B","C"]

console.log(arr)
console.log(arr2)

const removeIdx = 1

arr.splice(removeIdx, 1)
arr2.splice(removeIdx, 1)

console.log(arr)
console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: _"When asking a question show your example code and go into more detail"_ - If that's missing, then why did you answer it? And what (non-existing) problem does your answer solve?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Shouldn't have - still learning ;)

Comment: Oh I didn't know that sorry my apologies.

Comment: Also I do have an example code kinda thing.
Like if(levela[i] == blist[i]) {
         levela.splice(i, 1)
         blist.splice(i, 1)}
Like this